# .gz file to pandas DataFrame with hive delimiter

Tags: python, pandas, hive, paramiko, csv

I am getting a very odd result when I try to load my .gz data file.

My code is pretty simple

```
dt = pd.read_table(gzip.open(file.gz))
```

but I get a very odd delimiter. I had expected a tab ('\t') but iPython sees it as a [WHITE LEFT-POINTING TRIANGLE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25c1/index.htm). Most other programs do not see it at all. [image]

The data originally comes from hive through paramiko, if that matters I can give more details. Does anybody have a suggestion for how to delimit on such a thing?

EDIT:

```
print(gzip.open("file.gz").read()[-5])
```

Returns exactly this character.

And

```
In [28] gzip.open("file.gz").read()[-5]
Out[28]: '\x01'
```

Comment: what does `print(gzip.open(file.gz).read()[-5])` show? (edit your question to include that info if possible)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
pd.read_table("file.gz",compression='gzip',sep='\x01')
```

or

```
pd.read_table(gzip.open('file.gz'),sep='\x01')
```

Will both do it.